# How to convert string to an template reference instance?

Tags: angular, angular-template-variable

I'm setting up ngTemplateOutlet inside *ngFor like in below code snippet

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.type"></ng-container>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Where `list = [ {type: 'templateOne'}, {type: 'templateTwo'} ]` and i have defined templates like below.

```
<ng-template #templateOne></ng-template>
<ng-template #templateTwo></ng-template>
```

The above template snippet is throwing error with message undermentioned

```
TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
    at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.js:21600)
    at NgTemplateOutlet.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgTemplateOutlet.ngOnChanges (common.js:4026)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22085)
```

Since `item.type` used in `ngTemplateOutlet` is of type string i am suspecting it is not getting resolved to templateReference variable.

How can i convert string to a templateReference instance?

Demonstration - [See this link for example and verify console for the error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-outlet-kps7sl)

Comment: Why you want convert string to template reference? Do you want to just show that string value?

Comment: What data do the items keep inside the list?

Comment: I have defined [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.type" and expecting `item.type` to have different names corresponding to template reference variables.

Comment: The most appropriate answer i received is in github link below.
[https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30294#issuecomment-490393919](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30294#issuecomment-490393919)

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example:

```
    import { Component,ViewChild,TemplateRef,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of list;let i = index">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="list[i].type"></ng-container>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ng-template #templateOne>Template One</ng-template>
  <ng-template #templateTwo>Template Two</ng-template>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('templateTwo', {read: TemplateRef}) tpl1: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('templateOne', {read: TemplateRef}) tpl2: TemplateRef<any>;
  list;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.list=[{"type":this.tpl1},{"type":this.tpl2}];
    }

}
```

[Reference link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

[Working example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-outlet-mhpnas?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: We will see the same error, see this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-outlet-kps7sl

Comment: This requires us to go over the response and update it with TemplateRef before we can use it in template which is overhead..

Comment: That is not possible due to type safe binding you can do [ngIf] on template and use loop by ngFor on list and match and load only ng-template not required ng-container

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually how do we treat a string as a templateReferance variable in a template html.
If you do not have to handle it that way, you can just try this:

```
 @ViewChild('templateOne') templateOne: ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('templateTwo') templateTwo: ElementRef;
  list;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = [ {type: this.templateOne}, {type: this.templateTwo} ];
  }
```

Comment: This requires me to map the response from server and add the corresponding `ElementRef` to the type.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can create pure function that does mapping/conversion:

```
public map(type:string, ref1:TemplateRef, ref2:TemplateRef):TemplateRef {
   switch(type) {
      case 'templateTwo':
        return ref1;
      case 'templateTwo':
        return ref2;
      default:
        return ref1;
   }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="map(item.type, templateOne, templateTwo)"></ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Otherwise you will need access to template `context`:

```
public map(type:string):TemplateRef {
   return (this as any)[type]; // may break in future
}
```